# Visual Studio - limited properties of MVC application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012, windows-server-2012

I have solution with ASP.NET MVC project in it. It was created from Visual Studio's 2012 MVC 4 Facebook App template. So far it worked great. 
I have this solution on TFS, and after getting it into Windows Server 2012 machine, this is what I see, when I look in Properties window of MVC project. 
[image]

It also fails to create Virtual Directory for this project.

When I created new MVC application in the same machine, Properties window looks all right.
[image]

How may I "tell" Visual Studio, that this is a MVC project? Original project was created on Windows 7 machine.

Comment: What are the project type GUIDs for both your existing and a new MVC application?

Comment: They are exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

The properties missing from your first project appear when the Local IIS Web server is used.

You can change this setting in the properties for your project ==> Web ==> Servers:

[image]